# Authentication using a mySQL database in an iOS app

Tags: mysql, ios

I am building an application (for the iPad) in xCode (Xcode 5) and the app is almost ready but I am stuck on one thing. I want to make a login screen that authenticates the user and gives it acces to the app (so if the filled out data is correct it should basically go to another XIB).

I have an existing MySQL database I would like to use. It is build like this:
URL of the website is http://virtualtransavia.com/

```
$dbhost = "localhost";  //the host
$dbuser = "k116892_hv"; //the username
$dbpass = "******";     //the password
$dbname = "k116892_hv"; //the database name
$dbprefix = "IPS_";     //the table name prefix
```

The table it has to read is called IPS_Users (included the dbprefix) and the fields are "Email" and "Pass" (without the cuotation marks).

The password is encrypted for example like this: 0495769618c5515ef7d5d42c600cf66a14341b10.

So it just has to read out of the database and check if the username and password are correct. And it would be nice if it could remember someones login details.

Answer (score 0):

First, create PHP on server to handle a web request that will contain the user login information and authenticate the user (you should be able to do the authentication part this using the answer from user3013545).

In iOS you are going to want to create an NSURLRequest and post the appropriate data to the PHP you created above.  An easy way to post the data to the website is formatting it using JSON (Google, tons of info out there) and put it in your request.

This is an overview of course, but if I understand your question correctly NSURLRequest is where you want to start.  Here is the documentation...

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -1):

Connect to DB:

```
$db_host = "";         //Hostname
$db_user = "";         //Database user
$db_pass = "";         //Databse password for user
$db = "";              //Database to be 

 try{
        $db_pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $db_host . ";dbname=" . $db, $db_user, $db_pass);} 
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Select table and fields:

```
$columnEmail = '';
$columnPass = '';
$Table = '';
$st = $db_pdo->prepare("SELECT " . $column . ", " . $columnPass . " FROM " . $Table );
$st->execute();
//check if username and password exist
if($st->rowCount() > 0 ){
    echo 'User correct';
} else {
    echo 'User incorrect';
}
```

Since the password is cripted(or hashed?) you'll have to perform some stuff before checking for password validity.

Comment: Oh...sorry man. Got sorted by "PHP" tags so I assumed it was about PHP.